# Tabbed ios application with multiple table views

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I'm using XCode 4.2 and testing my build on iPad 5.0.

I started building an application using the standard Tabbed application in XCode and then added code to have 2 uitableviews inside the first tab.

It compiles, but the table data does not load into the view.

App delegate.h:

```
@interface dmbAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabBarController;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[dmbFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"dmbFirstViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[[dmbSecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"dmbSecondViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil];
    NSLog(@"Loading first tab view from app delegate...");
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

FirstViewController.h:

```
@interface dmbFirstViewController : UIViewController {

    ReservationsTable *reservationsController;
    WaitlistTable *waitlistController;
    IBOutlet UITableView *reserveTable;
    IBOutlet UITableView *waitlistTable;
}
```

FirstViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSLog(@"FirstView Controller - View Loading Started");

    [reserveTable setDataSource:reservationsController];
    [waitlistTable setDataSource:waitlistController];

    NSLog(@"FirstView Controller - Loading Table Views..");

    [reserveTable setDelegate:reservationsController];
    [waitlistTable setDelegate:waitlistController];
    reservationsController.view = reservationsController.tableView;
    waitlistController.view = waitlistController.tableView;

    NSLog(@"FirstView Controller - View Loading Finished");
}
```

Both the tables have a .h and .m with the standard table methods implemented. I also added 2 tables in the first view nib file and linked them to the file owner.

Update:
ReserveTable.h:

```
    @interface WaitlistTable : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>{
        NSMutableArray *waitlistitems;
    }
```

ReserveTable.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"View Did Load - Wait List Table");
    waitlistitems = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"6",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"11",@"12",@"13",@"14",@"15",@"16",@"17",nil] retain];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    NSLog(@"Inside number of section for Wait List table...");
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"Inside numberofRows for Wait List table...");
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [waitlistitems count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Inside cell for row at index path for Wait List table...");
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1.%@" ,[waitlistitems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];    
    return cell;
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: What does the code look like for reservationsController and waitListController?  And where are they initialized?

Comment: Added the code of waitlist controller in the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `viewDidLoad` to this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    reservationsController = [[ReservationsTable alloc] init];
    waitlistController = [[WaitlistTable alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"FirstView Controller - View Loading Started");

    [reserveTable setDataSource:reservationsController];
    [waitlistTable setDataSource:waitlistController];

    NSLog(@"FirstView Controller - Loading Table Views..");

    [reserveTable setDelegate:reservationsController];
    [waitlistTable setDelegate:waitlistController];

    NSLog(@"FirstView Controller - View Loading Finished");
 }
```

basically, you are never initializing your `tableViewControllers` (I guess that is the name of both of them, I would change their names to something like "WaitlistTableViewController" and "ReservationsTableViewController", but that is just me.)  Also, setting the 'tableView' to the 'view' is unnecessary.

Or even better, initialize them in the init method for your `dmbFirstViewController`.

Or just use `dmbFirstViewController` like this:

dmbFirstViewController.h:

```
@interface dmbFirstViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

    ReservationsTable *reservationsController;
    WaitlistTable *waitlistController;
    IBOutlet UITableView *reserveTable;
    IBOutlet UITableView *waitlistTable;
    NSMutableArray *waitlistitems;
    NSMutableArray *reserveitems;
}
```

dmbFirstViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    waitlistitems = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"6",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"11",@"12",@"13",@"14",@"15",@"16",@"17",nil] retain];

    NSLog(@"FirstView Controller - View Loading Started");

    [reserveTable setDataSource:self];
    [waitlistTable setDataSource:self];

    NSLog(@"FirstView Controller - Loading Table Views..");

    [reserveTable setDelegate:self];
    [waitlistTable setDelegate:self];

    NSLog(@"FirstView Controller - View Loading Finished");
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [reserveTable reloadData];
    [waitlistTable reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    NSLog(@"Inside number of section for Wait List table...");
    if(tableView == waitlistTable)
    {
        //Return sections for waitlistTable
        return 1;
    }else{
        //Return sections for reservedTable
        return 1;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(tableView==waitlistTable)
    {
        NSLog(@"Inside numberofRows for Wait List table...");
        // Return the number of rows in waitlistTable section.
        return [waitlistitems count];
    }else{
        // Return the number of rows in reservedTable section.
        return [reserveditems count];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if(tableView == waitlistTable)
    { 
        NSLog(@"Inside cell for row at index path for Wait List table...");
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1.%@" ,[waitlistitems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];    
        return cell;
    } else {
        //Create cell for reservedTable Cell
        .....
        return cell;
    }
}
```

You'll have to finish off the part about `reservedTable` cells, I didn't have that code.  Plus, I guessed on the items array for `reservedTable` and did not initialize it.

Comment: I refactored the names of the classes, and added your code to initialize them. It still does not work.

Comment: My last bit of advice would be to try and reload the data once your view appears.  Try `[reserveTable reloadData]; [waitlistTable reloadData];` in the `viewDidAppear:` method for `dmbFirstViewController`

Comment: Or, like mentioned below, use `dmbFirstViewController` as the `datasource` and `delegate` for both of the `UITableView`s.  I can post code if you need help doing it like that.

Comment: I tried reloadData and it still didnt work. I think the tables are not connected to their data source.

Comment: Sure, can you show me some sample code to have the code for both tables in the same view?

Comment: Also, with my current code, the NSLog inside cellForRowAtIndexPath method never appears.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your `firstViewController` you should push the views.
Assuming that `reserveTable` is your main table, push it like so

```
[self.view addSubView:reserveTable];
```

Also, did you import the `ReserveTable.h` to your `firstViewController`?

If yes, you should initialize the table there though.

But what i suggest, though, is to transform the `firstViewController` in a `tableViewController`, editing the `App Delegat`e and the `firstViewController.h` and m, and from there initialize the table (even adding the other one too). So that would be easier!

Comment: Yes I did import reseretable class in my firstviewcontroller header file.

Comment: If I wanted to convert firstviewcontroller into table view controller, how would I load two different tables in it?

Comment: Try to change it to a tableViewController. Just put the methods you have in your reserveTable into the firstViewController

Comment: Gave it a shot with a single table first, keeps crashing...working on it.

Comment: Thanks Pheel, your solution of transforming firstViewController into tableViewController worked and is easier!